# how to send two number in serial port sequential using c#

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I want to send two number from c# to serial monitor. But when I send numbers sequentially, port didn't work
My c# codes:

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                int MyInt = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt);
                serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 4);
                if (MyInt == 3)
                {
                    int MyInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                    byte[] s = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt2);
                    serialPort1.Write(s, 0, 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Continue");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check your connction maybe serial port is not connected");
            }
```

And Arduino codes:

```
int LedPin = 12;
int k, s;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    k = Serial.read();
    switch (k)
    {
      case 1:
        openCloseThree();
        break;
      case 2:
        openCloseTwice();
        break;
      case 3:
        s = Serial.read();
        if (s !=0)
        {
          openCloseIwanted();
        }
        break;
      default:
        openCloseIwanted();
        break;
    }
  }
}
void openClose()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  {
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
  }
}
void openCloseTwice()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
  }
}
void openCloseThree()
{

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
  }
}
void openCloseIwanted()
{
  s = Serial.read();
  for (int i = 0; i < s ; i++)
  {
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

My critical number is 3. I want to see led open-close when I send 3 and 5 for example, led must be open-close five times.
Please help me!

Comment: What exactly does "didn't work" mean? do you receive on the arduino side only the 3? only the 5? nothing?

Comment: So, led did't open-close,when I send bigger than 2 after I send 3.

Comment: so when you send a 3 and then a 2 again it blinks 2 times?

Comment: Yes,exactly true

Comment: my guess is that it is a timing issue. I guess the arduino is reading the second value into `k` and executing `openCloseTwice();`

Comment: Yes,But I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: you are writing 4 bytes on the C# side, can you read them on the arduino as byte array? because then you could use the first byte as the option of what to do and the second byte as the amount of "blinks"

Answer (score 2):

I solved my question and ı want to share here. 
My arduino part:

```
int number[3];
int n;
int i = 0;
int led = 12;
int led2=7;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    n = Serial.read();
    if (i < 3)
    {
      number[i] = n;
      switch (number[0])
      {
        case 1:
          openClose();
          break;
        case 2:
          openCloseTwice();
          break;
        case 3:
          if (i == 2)
          {
            for (int j = 0; j < number[1]; j++)
            {
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(led, LOW);
            }
            delay(500);
            for (int k = 0; k < number[2]; k++)
            {
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      i = 0;
    }

  }
}
void openClose()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  {
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
}
void openCloseTwice()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
}
```

and my c# part:

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            int MyInt = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt);
            serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 1);

            int MyInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            byte[] z = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt2);
            serialPort1.Write(z, 0, 1);

            int MyInt3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            byte[] p = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt3);
            serialPort1.Write(p, 0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please control your connection");
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just saw this, great. A bit more explanation of what you fixed and what was the problem would have been better, though. :)

Comment: I only exchanged serialPort1.Write(p,0,4) with serialPort1.Write(p,0,1)!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues in your code.

- you call `Serial.read()` here:

  ```cpp
    case 3:
      s = Serial.read();
      if (s !=0)
      {
        openCloseIwanted();
      }
  ```

  but you actually don't know whether a `byte` is already available on `Serial` or not.
- you call **again** `Serial.read()` here:

  ```cpp
  void openCloseIwanted()
  {
    s = Serial.read();
    for (int i = 0; i < s ; i++)
    {
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
    }
  }
  ```

  without checking whether a `byte` is available on `Serial` or not.
- You send `4 bytes` in your `C#` source code, not `1`:

  ```cpp
  if (MyInt == 3)
  {
      int MyInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
      byte[] s = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt2);
      serialPort1.Write(s, 0, 4);
  }
  ```

  as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx) of `write()`. If you send `4 bytes`, you *should not* read only `1`, or even `2` but in an independent / unrelated manner.

---

If you send `4 bytes`, then you should:

- wait for at least `4 bytes` to be available on input:

  ```
  while (Serial.available() < 4) { };
  ```
- then store those bytes into a `long` variable:

  ```cpp
  unsigned long lvar = 0;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      lvar = (lvar << 8) + (byte) Serial.read();
  }
  ```

  You need a `unsigned long` because an `int` on *Arduino* has only `2` bytes.
- then pass `lval` as *argument* to your function `void openCloseIwanted(unsigned long lval)`

Perhaps a better solution is to send only `1 byte` in your `C#` code, I don't think that you need more than `255` blinks, do you?

---

Please note that it might *not be sufficient* to fix the code in `case 3:`, because you are sending `4 bytes` also the first time around for `1, 2, 3`. Depending on *byte endianess* of your architecture, the leading `0`s of the original `int` in `C#` might be parsed either before or after reading the `byte` containing `1, 2, 3`. This means that you might get a potentially *misaligned* reading of your data through `Serial`.

Why don't you send/receive values encoded in their *ASCII* representation, instead of trying to perform *binary* input/output? That should be easier to handle.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137343/discussion-on-answer-by-patrick-trentin-how-to-send-two-number-in-serial-port-se).

Comment: Np, have fun! \o